# Как можно не закрывать попап пока не нажали на крестик?

Tags: vue.js

ведь если я перейду на другую страницу, то он закроется

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Сохраняйте состояние попапа в localStorage